# GitHub overwriting work on push.

Tags: git, github

I've been working with a three man team using github and netbeans to work on the same project. On multiple occasions while working independently we've tried to merge our branches into the trunk which sometimes result in some of our changes being overwritten by the next commit and push/merge. Instead of trying to figure out what we're doing wrong would it be possible for someone to give me a quick description from the point of view of a single programmer as to how to get work from his branch to the main trunk without removing working that another programmer has done.

I could go with more detail but I'd just like Step 1, Step 2, ... Steps that all three of us can follow so to not step on each others toes. Assume we are fresh out of code monkey school and have never used Github. (Github is already setup on netbeans)

Answer (score 0):

1. Dev A & Dev B are working on the same branch
2. Dev A & B start their day after a `git clone` or `pull` to have the same codebase.
3. At some point Dev A will `commit`, and `push` his changes.
4. When Dev B wants to also to commit his changes he should commit `git commit -a -m "something"`, pull the changes `git pull origin yourbranch`, and push again `git push origin yourbranch`.

This step should create a merge commit because you have done a commit based on the history you had, and when you pull the changes it has to rewrite the history based on dev A.